# giving unique id to each form post to later grab

Tags: php, forms, unique

is there anyway I can give each post a unique id, so something like quote_id that is unique to that post and that post alone, I am creating a liking system so i need this to put down so that when a user likes a post, it puts that quote_id down, so i can later grab it to identify what the user liked, can anyone give any suggestions?

```
<form name = "quoted" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" required="required" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     <br>
 <textarea class = "actual_quote" name = "actual_quote" required="required" placeholder = "Write the question here!"></textarea><br><br><br>
 <div class = "checkboxes" required="required">
     <h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Please select one catagory that the quote falls into.</h3>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="formtype" value="Inspirational" id = "inspirational.php" checked="checked" />    <span>Inspirational</span></label><br>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="formtype" value="Funny" id = "funny.php"   /> <span>Funny</span>    </label><br>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="formtype" value="OutofContext" id = "outofcontext.php"/>    <span>OutofContext</span></label>
 </div>
 <input id = "submit1" name="submit1" type="submit"><br>
 </form>
<div class = "contain-info">
        <p style = "float: left; font-size:14px;"><strong>Creator:</strong> Write your own name or the creator of the quote here!</p><br>
        <p style = "float: left; font-size:14px;"><strong>Quote:</strong> Write the quote you thought of or found here!</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
$db_name = 'submissions';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost;dbname=submissions', $db_user, $db_pass);
$formtype = (empty($_POST['formtype'])) ? : $_POST['formtype'] ;
$poster = (empty($_POST['poster'])) ? : $_POST['poster'] ;
$actual_quote = (empty($_POST['actual_quote'])) ? : $_POST['actual_quote'] ;
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (actual_quote, poster, formtype) VALUES (    :actual_quote, :poster, :formtype)");
$query->bindParam(':formtype', $formtype, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindParam(':poster', $poster, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindParam(':actual_quote', $actual_quote, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->execute();
?>
```

Comment: are you asked how to generate a random Id for posts or how to implement a random id into your form?

Comment: If you're after unique IDs, consider using an `auto_increment` column in your database. Each ID will be unique as it will just be one more than the previous.

Comment: Yes, but I have to keep generating and grabbing ones without having to call out specific numbers, i would need to use something like WHERE in this situation, how would I grab the id of the row without grabbing all the rows and doing this without listing the exact number?